# Is there a word for person who have to always read anything written or printed anything and anywhere?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for person who always have to read anything written or printed either the graffiti on wall something printed on t shirt, behind or on side of the transport literally almost everything  no matter the situation. Sometime he/she makes it awkward in-front of other people.More curious type of person but sometime annoying.

Edit 1: That word that clearly implies the behavioral pattern as mentioned by @Spagirl.

Comment: Do you mean they seem immune to sarcasm and humour?

Comment: "Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. **As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.** See the [How to Ask page](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question."

Comment: I feel most of the comments are seeking to name *causes* of the behaviour, when the questions is whether there is a name for the specific behaviour; which I don't believe there is.

Comment: @Kece36 I didn't meant it as some kind of mental disease but particularly a  behavioral pattern

Comment: They  [would read the back of the cereal box](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=would+read+the+back+of+the+cereal+box). But that doesn't mean out loud - do you?

Comment: @marcellothearcane No sarcasm or pun intended and none taken by the person. It's probably just a human pattern for particular action  :)

Comment: @Chris H That could be possible too.

Comment: It's not a real word, but the question made me google for **Omnivoracious**, and I'm clearly not the first!

Comment: @Steve Lovell that might be it. Thank you for your effort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*A **voracious reader***, and anything shorter will be confusing.

Here's an example from [Google Books](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=S6tWBhnAq-EC&pg=PA17&lpg=PA17&dq=would%20read%20the%20back%20of%20the%20cereal%20box&source=bl&ots=deekdiCZqi&sig=GQnSIOG3HpUSIBPZdgStqW8yLDo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiArtKslJPVAhUCalAKHYVFAwAQ6AEIYDAN#v=onepage&q=would%20read%20the%20back%20of%20the%20cereal%20box&f=false), found using Chris H's suggestion in the comments:

[image: Rescued by Prayer By Sandy Ourso]

*Voracious* -- [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/voracious)

> If you describe a person, or their appetite for something, as voracious, you mean that they want a lot of something.
>
> *Joseph Smith was a voracious book collector.*
> *He read voraciously.*

There's also a rare (fancy, made-up) word, like Steve Lovell mentioned in the comments:

***Omnivoracious*** -- [Encyclo](http://www.encyclo.co.uk/meaning-of-omnivoracious)

> 2. Mentally striving to find and learn all existing forms of information beyond what is considered a normal acquisition:
>    *He had an omnivoracious desire for knowledge about everything; both past and present.*

Comment: Nice answer. I thought of voracious but was not familiar with omnivoracious. I thought of *polymath* instead but, yes, omnivoracious is a better word likely. I think in this case they are just describing a highly inquisitive person that has some strange social idiosynchrocies; but that's a great word :)